# CMakePresets: How can I add command line arguments to the cmake build?

Tags: cmake, command-line-arguments, visual-studio-2022, ninja, cmake-presets

I have a CMakeLists.txt in combination with CMakePresets.json, Visual Studio 2022 and the generator ninja.
Running the build command in Visual Studio 2022 executes

```
cmake --build --preset Release
```

My goal is that running the build command in Visual Studio 2022 executes

```
cmake --build --preset Release | my_script.bat
```

where my_script.bat is a custom script which takes the output of cmake build as stdin and generates a new output which is displayed in Visual Studio 2022.

Unfortunately, I have not found any CMakePresets option to do this. My ansatz was to use the CMakePresets option "nativeToolOptions", this is

```
{
    "version": 3,
    "configurePresets": [
    ...
    ],
    "buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "Release",
            "configurePreset": "Release",
            "nativeToolOptions": ["foo"]
        }
    ]
}
```

which results in

```
cmake --build --preset Release -- "foo"
```

I tried to break out of nativeToolOptions but I was not successful.